# Extract names of restaurants from web page

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am just able to get the name of first restaurant i.e. "toit" using these commands:

```
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
url <- html("https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/restaurants?page=1")
url %>% html_node("li a.result-title") %>% html_text()
```

How can I adjust this to extract all restaurant names from the web page?

Comment: This question violates X.29 of the site's [ToC](https://www.zomato.com/conditions)'s. Anyone helping is also in violation of said ToC's.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `html_nodes` and not `html_node`:

```
    url %>% html_nodes("li a.result-title") %>% html_text()

 [1] "Toit "                              "Truffles "                          "Church Street Social "             
 [4] "AB's - Absolute Barbecues "         "Onesta "                            "The Black Pearl "                  
 [7] "The Hole in the Wall Cafe "         "Arbor Brewing Company "             "Big Brewsky "                      
[10] "Chutney Chang "                     "Soho St. "                          "Glen's Bakehouse "                 
[13] "Fenny's Lounge And Kitchen "        "SodaBottleOpenerWala "              "The Black Rabbit "                 
[16] "High Ultra Lounge "                 "Prost Brew Pub "                    "LOFT38 "                           
[19] "Windmills Craftworks "              "Smoke House Deli "                  "Tim Tai "                          
[22] "Vapour Pub & Brewery "              "Big Pitcher "                       "Punjab Grill "                     
[25] "Brewsky "                           "Hard Rock Cafe "                    "The Boozy Griffin "                
[28] "The Glass House - Deli Bistro Bar " "The Fatty Bao - Asian Gastro Bar "  "Monkey Bar "
```